# active recored where statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

In codeigniter I am trying to produce the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`ea_users`,`ea_appointments`,`ea_services`) 
WHERE `ea_appointments`.`id_users_customer` = `ea_users`.`id` 
AND `ea_appointments`.`id_services` = `ea_services`.`id` 
AND `ea_appointments`.`start_datetime`> '2015-07-18 00:00:00'
AND `ea_appointments`.`start_datetime`< '2015-07-18 23:59:59'
```

In the Active Record format I have tried this:

```
$day_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $day);
$day_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $day);
return $this->db->select('*')
  ->from('ea_appointments,ea_services,ea_users')
  ->where('ea_appointments.id_users_customer','ea_users.id') 
  ->where('ea_appointments.id_services','ea_services.id')
  ->where('ea_appointments.start_datetime>',$day_start)
  ->where('ea_appointments.start_datetime<',$day_end)
  ->get()->result();
```

But it produces this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ea_appointments`, `ea_services`, `ea_users`)
WHERE `ea_appointments`.`id_users_customer` =  'ea_users.id'
AND `ea_appointments`.`id_services` =  'ea_services.id'
AND `ea_appointments`.`start_datetime>` '2015-07-18 00:00:00'
AND `ea_appointments`.`start_datetime<` '2015-07-18 23:59:59'
```

How do I get 'ea_users.id' and 'ea_services.id' to be translated as 'ea_users'.'id' and 'ea_services'.'id'?  I have tried:

```
  ->where('ea_appointments.id_users_customer','ea_users'.'id') 
  ->where('ea_appointments.id_services','ea_services'.'id')
```

But that produces this:

```
WHERE `ea_appointments`.`id_users_customer` =  'ea_usersid'
AND `ea_appointments`.`id_services` =  'ea_servicesid'
```

What is the correct format?

Comment: Why does it matter if your sql output is like this: `'ea_users'.'id' ` rather than like this: `'ea_users.id'` ? MYSQL should be able to differentiate.

Comment: Unclear what you asking.But remember if you use any operator in where function must use an space.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
(A space before the > < signs)

```
$day_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $day);
$day_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $day);
return $this->db->select('*')
->from('ea_appointments,ea_services,ea_users')
->where('ea_appointments.id_users_customer','ea_users.id') 
->where('ea_appointments.id_services','ea_services.id')
->where('ea_appointments.start_datetime >',$day_start)
->where('ea_appointments.start_datetime <',$day_end)
->get()->result();
```

Comment: Those little spaces.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I thought it worked but it does not.  `ea_users`.`id` and `ea_services`.`id` is what is needed (left leaning apostrophes).  It matters.  I have tried it with out and in other configurations and it produces null both in code igniter and directly in phpMyAdmin.  Only with the left leaning apostrophes do I get what is needed.  Codeigniter puts them in for the first variable but not the other.  So, any thoughts?

Comment: The left leaning apostrophes are not doing anything in this SQL. Any errors in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original sql function works as you intended it before you tried to recreate it in codeigniter, You can simply do this.

```
$day_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $day);
$day_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $day);

$query = $this->db->query(SELECT * 
FROM (ea_users, ea_appointments, ea_services) 
WHERE ea_appointments.id_users_customer = ea_users.id 
AND ea_appointments.id_services = ea_services.id 
AND ea_appointments.start_datetime > {$day_start}
AND ea_appointments.start_datetime < {$day_end});

$query->result();
```

Comment: Yes, that does work but I was trying to stay within codeigniters active record format.  I am no expert but my understanding is that it was designed for better security.  That seems like a good thing especially when it comes to client information so I am going with it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$day_start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $day);
$day_end = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $day);
return $this->db->select('ea_appointments.id,
 ea_appointments.start_datetime,
 ea_appointments.end_datetime, 
 ea_users.email, 
 ea_services.name')
  ->from('ea_appointments')
  ->join('ea_users', 'ea_appointments.id_users_customer = ea_users.id','left') 
  ->join('ea_services', 'ea_appointments.id_services = ea_services.id','left')
  ->where('ea_appointments.start_datetime >',$day_start)
  ->where('ea_appointments.start_datetime <',$day_end)
  ->get()->result();
```

Join statements did the trick.